# Display %change using SQL Server

Tags: sql

I was wondering how to write a SQL query in SQL Server that displays the %change.

Example, I am running this simple query with the output:

```
Select location, item_sold
from product

Location    Item_sold
VA           20
CA           57
DC           44
MA           75
FL           101
```

Now, I would like the desired output as follow, which take the item sold from each location divided by the total.

```
Location    Item_sold         %Chg
VA           20              7%
CA           57              19% 
DC           44              15%
MA           75              25%
FL           101             34%
TOTAL         297
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: i am using SQL server version 2000/5/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+, you can use the following:

```
SELECT location, item_sold, CAST(item_Sold AS FLOAT)/(SUM(Item_Sold) OVER()) [%Chg]
FROM product
```

For previous versions, try this:

```
SELECT A.location, A.item_sold, 
       CAST(A.item_Sold AS FLOAT)/(SELECT SUM(Item_Sold) Ammount FROM product) [%Chg]
FROM product A
```

Comment: Thanks Lamak. It works. However, it does not show the decimal in the % column from either above queries. The item_sold is integer.

Comment: No problem. In any case, it should return you with decimals, thats why I did a CAST on item_sold. Maybe you should change it to CAST(item_sold AS NUMERIC(16,4)) or similar, to explicitly define the decimals it should show.

Comment: Hi Lamak, I tried various methods below and the %column still shows as int. Not sure why.

Comment: SELECT location, item_sold, CAST(item_Sold AS FLOAT)/(SUM(Item_Sold) OVER(PARTITION BY Location)) as [%Chg] FROM product 
--query1

Comment: @joe: please **don't** put large code blocks into comments - they're **very hard** to read! Please update your original question by editing it to provide additional information!

Comment: The product table is a temp table which i created as select location, sum(item_sold) from sometable group by location. Not sure if it has something to do with the conversion.

Comment: SELECT location, item_sold, CAST(item_Sold AS numeric(12, 1))/(SUM(Item_Sold) OVER(PARTITION BY Location)) as [%Chg] FROM product 
--query2

Comment: SELECT location, item_sold, convert(DECIMAL(16, 1), APPS)/(SUM(Item_Sold) OVER(PARTITION BY Location)) as [%Chg] FROM product 
--query3

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer, as I understood your question wrong. I thought that you needed the percentage between each record against the total of a location, not the total of all the table. It should work fine now.

Comment: @LamakThanks very much! I truly appreciate your help!